# Unable to mount CDROM on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, vmware

I have problem with using CDROM on Solaris 10. When I mount any ISO using VMware, ISO is not being visible under Solaris.

1. When I go to CDROM there is nothing inside:

   ```
   --- 134 # cd /cdrom
   --- 135 # ls -lart
   total 9
   drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           2 Jan  3 10:36 test
   drwxr-xr-x   3 root     nobody         3 Jan  3 10:36 .
   drwxr-xr-x  29 root     root          32 Jan  3 15:03 ..
   ```
2. I can try to mount CDROM manually, for example using the following command:

   ```
   --- 136 # mount -F hsfs -o ro /dev/dsk/c0t0d0 /cdrom/test

   mount: No such device

   mount: cannot mount /dev/dsk/c0t0d0
   ```

   This is because I can't find information abount the physical name of my CDROM - in the following format: c1t1d0, c1t2d0, c2t1d0 etc.
3. IOSTAT command gives me results:

   ```
   --- 137 # iostat -E
   sd0       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: VMware   Product: Virtual disk     Revision: 1.0  Serial No:
   Size: 26.84GB <26843545088 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 3 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   sd2       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: VMware   Product: Virtual disk     Revision: 1.0  Serial No:
   Size: 21.47GB <21474835968 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 3 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   sd4       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: VMware   Product: Virtual disk     Revision: 1.0  Serial No:
   Size: 107.37GB <107374181888 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 3 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   sd5       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: NECVMWar Product: VMware IDE CDR00 Revision: 1.00 Serial No:
   Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 2 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   sd6       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: NECVMWar Product: VMware IDE CDR01 Revision: 1.00 Serial No:
   Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 2 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0

   --- 138 # iostat -En

   c1t0d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: VMware   Product: Virtual disk     Revision: 1.0  Serial No:
   Size: 26.84GB <26843545088 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 3 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   c1t2d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: VMware   Product: Virtual disk     Revision: 1.0  Serial No:
   Size: 21.47GB <21474835968 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 3 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   c1t1d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: VMware   Product: Virtual disk     Revision: 1.0  Serial No:
   Size: 107.37GB <107374181888 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 3 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   sd5              Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: NECVMWar Product: VMware IDE CDR00 Revision: 1.00 Serial No:
   Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 2 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   sd6              Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
   Vendor: NECVMWar Product: VMware IDE CDR01 Revision: 1.00 Serial No:
   Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
   Illegal Request: 2 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
   ```
4. When trying to use script which was found on Stackoverflow I have resutls:

   ```
   --- root@solaio03 : /cdrom
   --- 139 # iostat -x|tail -n +3|awk '{print $1}'>/tmp/f0.txt.$$
   iostat -nx|tail -n +3|awk '{print "/dev/dsk/"$11}'>/tmp/f1.txt.$$
   paste -d= /tmp/f[01].txt.$$
   rm /tmp/f[01].txt.$$
   --- root@solaio03 : /cdrom
   --- 140 # iostat -nx|tail -n +3|awk '{print "/dev/dsk/"$11}'>/tmp/f1.txt.$$

   --- root@solaio03 : /cdrom
   --- 141 # paste -d= /tmp/f[01].txt.$$
   sd0=/dev/dsk/c1t0d0
   sd2=/dev/dsk/c1t2d0
   sd4=/dev/dsk/c1t1d0
   sd5=/dev/dsk/sd5
   sd6=/dev/dsk/sd6
   nfs1=/dev/dsk/solaio03.sys.net:vold(pid747)
   ```
5. And now my final question: Is there anybody which can give me any advice what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should rebuild `/dev`:

```
devfsadm -v
```

After that, proper c*t*d*s* devices should appear and be usable.

Note that a manual mount should use the "whole disk" slice (`s2`), something like:

```
mount -F hsfs -o ro /dev/dsk/cxtydzs2 /cdrom/test
```

Comment: Perfect answer. It helped. Many thanks! After rebooting the server I wasn't even forced to mount the CDROM manually as everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

```
svcs volfs
```

if needed enable it `svcadm enable volfs`

if all is working you should see your cdrom mounted in `/media/<label of the cdrom>`

Comment: --- 182 # svcs volfs
STATE          STIME    FMRI
online         12:13:24 svc:/system/filesystem/volfs:default

Comment: `--- 182 # svcs volfs
STATE          STIME    FMRI
online         12:13:24 svc:/system/filesystem/volfs:default` I think that problem is visible when running "iostat -En" command as the CDROM is not being show as, for example c1t3d0s2 but sd5